# Using one of the results of an sql assoc array in a different function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make use of one of the results of the assoc. array of an sql query outside its original function.
i.e I want to make use of one of the values of the assoc array of query in a totally different function. 
I first made it a variable and then globalized. Then
I tried to echo it outside its parent function but there was nothing visible. Please refer to my code for
clarity. Or can I run a different function inside the mysqli fetch array function?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('server.php');

$gat = "";

if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){
    $query = "select * from users";
    $conditions = array();

    if(! empty($firstname)){
        $conditions[] = "firstname='$firstname'";
    }

    if(! empty($lastname)){
        $conditions[] = "lastname='$lastname'";
    }

    if(! empty($gender)){
        $conditions[] = "gender='$gender'";
    }

    $sql = $query;
    if(count($conditions) > 0){
        $sql .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($users = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $users['firstname'];

        $users['firstname'] = $gat;
        GLOBAL $gat;
        $users['lastname'];
        $users['id'];
    }       

    //tried to echo value outside to be used for different function.

    echo $gat; 
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't see $gat being assigned any value at all.  But why not just wrap all that in a function that returns $gat.  Or create a class?

Comment: You say "outside its original function". Is the code you posted actually inside a function? If not, what original function are you talking about?

Comment: The best way to use something outside the function that sets it is to return it as the function's value. Then you can pass that value as an argument to some other function.

Comment: The `echo` statement will only echo the name from the last row of results. If you want to echo all the names, put that line inside the loop. And if you want to send all of them to another function, you should put them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need to use `GLOBAL` here. The variable `$gat` is defined in the outer most scope so it will be available anywhere in the file.

Your problems are here. You are setting $users['firstname'] to be equal to the value of `$gat` which at this point is an empty string: "". You want to do the opposite, set `$gat = $users['firstname']`.

So turn these lines:

```
$users['firstname'];
$users['firstname'] = $gat;
GLOBAL $gat;
$users['lastname'];
$users['id'];
```

Into:

```
$users['firstname']; // 1
$gat = $users['firstname']; // 2
$users['lastname']; // 3
$users['id']; // 4
```

Also, I'm not sure about what your exact intention is but lines 1, 3, and 4 are doing nothing.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But why is 'echo $gat' unable to display outside the mysqli_fetch_array function? Thanks

Comment: It is... it just is an empty string and an empty string doesn't look like much.

Answer (score 0):

You're not inside any function that would restrict access to the mysql result.  $gat is never assigned a value, rather you are assigning  $users['firstname'] to $gat, which was originally set to "".

Comment: ok... pls how do I fix this? I need to use a result of the query to perform another operation.

Comment: You can use those variables directly in your other operation like this :: $users['firstname'] or $users['lastname'].  Or you can assign them to new variables like $firstName = $users['firstname'] or $lastName = $users['lastname'].  Hope that's making sense.  Can you show your other operation?

Comment: Hi... but is there a way that variable $firstName can be globalized to be used anywhere in the program? And again would a different function/operation be appropriate inside mysqli_fetch_array function?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see the function you're talking about.  You should be fine to use those variables anywhere in your program as it is displayed.

Comment: Try what Jordan stated :: $gat = $users['firstname'];  and then run your program.  The "echo $gat;" will then work.  You can also do "echo $users['lastname'];" and that will also work.